# SwiftUI - Firebase: Value of type 'String' has no member 'documentID'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

When I try to get user data from firebase I have an error. The error message is:

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'documentID'

The line with the error is the line `fetchUser(uid: uid.documentID) { (user) in`:

```
let title = doc.document.data()["title"] as? String ?? "No Title"
let time = doc.document.data()["time"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
let pic = doc.document.data()["url"] as? String ?? "No URL"
let uid = doc.document.data()["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                                       
// getting user Data...
 fetchUser(uid: uid.documentID) { (user) in
```

And this is my FetchUser model:

```
// Global Refernce
let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
    
    ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        guard let user = doc else{return}
        
        let username = user.data()?["username"] as? String ?? "No Username"
        let pic = user.data()?["imageurl"] as? String ?? "No image URL"
        let bio = user.data()?["bio"] as? String ?? "No bio"
        let uid = user.data()?["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UserModel(username: username, pic: pic, bio: bio, uid: uid))
        }
    }
}
```

Below is code to that checks the users uid. On the line that starts "ref.collection..." the error "Cannot find 'uid' in scope" is thrown.

```
func checkUser(){

let ref = Firestore.firestore()

if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    
    let uid = currentUser.uid
} else {
    
    print("No Authenticated User")
return
}

ref.collection("Users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments { (snap, err) in
    
    if err != nil{
        // No Documents..
        // No User Found...
        self.registerUser.toggle()
        self.isLoading = false
        return
    }
    
    if snap!.documents.isEmpty{
        
        self.registerUser.toggle()
        self.isLoading = false
        return
    }
    self.log_Status = true
}
```

}

Comment: And what do you expect when you cast `uid` to String earlier in the code?

Comment: On firebase a uid (string) is generated automatically once a user has signed up. That's why I cast uid to String. Is this not necessary?

Comment: The problem is in `fetchUser(uid: uid.documentID)`. My guess is that you want `fetchUser(uid: uid)`.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my error but now I am getting:  "Document path cannot be empty." Im looking to load posts made by a user. None have been made. Is it possible to make a post through Firestore in the firebase console? (So it has something to load)

Comment: It would be very easy to add a little snippet of code to write some data as well but you can certainly do that in the Firebase console. It's not really clear from your code how you're assigning the `uid` var but it's probably nil which is why you're getting that error.

Comment: @Jay I am setting the user data to Firestore with the line: let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid. The user appears on firebase but as you say the uid var is probably nil because the document path is empty. Is there an issue with this line?

Comment: Yes there is. You're force-unwrapping an optional with the ! and that's generally not a good idea. A better idea is to protect your code by handling a situation where is is nil with a let, guard or nil-coalescing operator; something like `if let currentUser = Auth.auth.currentUser { let uid = currentUser.uid} else { print("oh my there is no authenticated user") return }` which will prevent your code from crashing and also alert you if the currentUser is nil

Comment: ahhh I see that's extremely helpful thanks!

Comment: @Jay When I made the changes I got the error: Cannot find 'uid' in scope. Do you know why is error occurs?

Comment: Well, I may know but it's hard to tell since we don't know what the current code looks like or where/how `uid` is defined. Can you add an edit to your *question* and include the updated code and clearly indicate which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take the first part of your code to show where the issue is. Note how much easier it is to read when properly formatted

```
func checkUser() {
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()

    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        //NOTE! Note that this area is encapsulated with brackets { and }
        //That means it's is own 'space' and anything defined in this area
        //only exists in this area
        let uid = currentUser.uid //<- uid only exists here
    } else {
        print("No Authenticated User")
        return
    }

    //uid no longer exists and cannot be referenced
    //  e.g. it's not in 'scope' at this point
    ref.collection("Users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
```

However, if you look at where the `let ref = Firestore` line is located, it's at the top level within the checkUser function and will exist throughout the function.

There are many way to do this; here's one using a `guard` statement

```
func checkUser() {
    let ref = Firestore.firestore()

    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        print("no user!")
        return
    }
    
    // currentUser flows through to here because it was created with
    //   a guard statement, so now we know it's populated and can
    //   get the uid property value from it
    let uid = currentUser.uid

    ref.collection("Users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
```

`guard` is pretty neat in that it not only allows you to instantiate a var while a the same time as protecting your code from a nil situation, it also allows the var to flow through to the code following the guard.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! That information will be extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm writting this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the issue reported.

The error came while trying to get the uid as `fetchUser(uid: uid.documentID)`, instead the correct way is by doing `fetchUser(uid: uid)`

Then an error mentioning `Document path cannot be empty` appeared, which was mainly due to the fact that no entries with were loaded, the best way to avoid this is to load documents on the consulted path without `nil` values